# Pandas check if a value exists using multiple conditions within group and count value if true

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transform

I've created a boolean column based on criteria I've identified. I'd like to take it a step farther by counting the True values per group.

I have

```
group = df.groupby('id')
df.loc[:,'Match'] = (group['flag'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(0).any()))&(group['flag'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(1).any()))
```

Which gives me True and False values. How can I then count the # of True values that are populated per id?

Sample data:

```
id   flag   Match  Count Match
123  0      True    3
123  1      True    3
123  1      True    3
567  0      False   0
567  0      False   0
```

The Match column is created above, then I'd like to create the Count Match column.

Comment: You should provide some sample data.

Comment: I've added some sample data @QuangHoang

Comment: There are 3 Trues for ID 123, however your count match column only has 2 in it for id 123. Is there a reason for this? or is it a typo?

Comment: That's a typo, I fixed it @CameronRiddell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it:

```
df['Count Match'] = df['Match'].astype(int).groupby(df['id']).transform('sum')
```

Comment: Missing the closing bracket in your column assignment. Tried to edit it for you, but it's only a 1 character change. `df['Count Match']`